# Permutations that preserve Cesaro mean

Tags: reference-request

Given a summable sequence $a_i$ of real numbers, theorems of Levi and later Agnew characterize the permutations $\pi: \mathbb N \mapsto \mathbb N$ which are sum preserveing: that is

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n a_{i} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n a_{\pi(i)} $$

I would like to know of any similar research into permutations that preserve the Cesaro mean. That is, given a sequence $b_i \in \ell^\infty$, is there any characterization of permutations which
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n b_i = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n b_{\pi(i)}$$

Comment: Do you really want the set S of permutations preserving a given Cesaro mean (thus S depends on the sequence $(b_i)\\ $), or the set of permutations that perserve *any* Cesaro mean ? 

Comment: I do mean the set $S$ of permutations preserving a given Cesaro mean. 

Comment: Permutations preserving Cesaro mean for any sequence would be the Levy group. See theorem 2 of 
M. Blümlinger; N. Obata  "Permutations preserving Cesàro mean, densities of natural numbers and uniform distribution of sequences" (1991)